# Regarding a word "Eyeballs" in a news

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I found [**an article**](https://headlines.yahoo.co.jp/hl?a=20190408-00000001-bloom_v-int) in my country about Youtube's inappropriate method to make money, and the narrator "seems to be" saying ( Excuse me if I heard incorrectly and in case if you can not listen to ( due to a border problem. ))

> "This is the first story I've read this morning, I know it's quite devastating. I think it sort of, reinforces the idea that we've all suspected, which is that these companies found a formula, --- a sort of, **to get eyeballs,** make money, the formula sort of came with a pretty significant baggage."

I think the word "eyeballs" falls under the definition of [**this page**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/eyeballs),

> 2. (Marketing) marketing slang (plural) viewers of a television program or website, esp seen as potential customers, advertisers, etc: The site's goal was to get more eyeballs for advertisers.

Am I wrong or correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @fred2 Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: I don't think that this can get any better definition than that in the dictionary.